# IOS API for unread email count

Tags: ios

Is there an IOS API that will let me read the number of unread emails in my email inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no API that allows you to get any information at all about email.

Comment: No. There is nothing to do what you want. 3rd party apps have NO knowledge about anything related to email or email accounts. A 3rd party app can send email using `MFMailComposeViewController` or you can access email addresses from contacts. That's it.

Comment: Can I get a count from an Exchange server and display it in my app?

Comment: Maybe. But that is an entirely different question. You should post a new question about that. This one has been answered (though not accepted).